# Extract string from two identical symbols javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

suppose I have a string :

[image]

I want to replace the above string as:

[image]

For this i tried as:

```
var result=[];
result=string.split("+");
console.log(result[1]);
```

It gives o/p: details.data

Now to replace the said part I tried as:

```
var res = string1.replace("+details.data+", ''+result[1]+'');
```

But it gives me o/p as: hello someting "+details.data+" still something

I want to replace exactly in the attachment.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't use images when you don't have to. Please take the time to type out your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use: str.replace("+details.data+", `\`+${result[1]}+\``) ?

This way you are replacing the string with a template literal which includes the result (evaluated to a string). It also includes the backticks in the string by escaping them with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is this:

```js
let string1 = "hello something +details.data+ hello something";
const result = ['data', 'yay! My data is here'];

const updatedString = string1.replace('+details.data+', `+${result[1]}+`);

console.log(updatedString);
```

By using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) we can easily replace the `details.data` with the `result` data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to replace `+details.data+` with the actual value of `details.data`

You need something like this:

```
var details = { data: 'blabla' }

const string = `hello something "+details.data+" still something`;
string = string.replace('+details.data+', details.data);

console.log(string); // hello something "blabla" still something
```

If you wanted this to be dynamic you would need the details object as a prop of another object:

```
var obj = { details: { data: 'blabla' }}

var arr = string.split('+'); // ['hello something "','details.data','" still something']
var path = arr[1].split('.'); // ['details', 'data']

// you would need some logic here to check that each of the props from path exists in obj
var value = obj[path[0]][path[1]];

string = string.replace('+details.data+', value);
console.log(string);
```